# How do I make center the text under the thumbnail in woocommerce

Tags: html, woocommerce

I am trying to center the text underneath my thumbnail on my website (woocommerce using the claue theme).

I would like for the product name and the price to be centered.

Thanks! Bianca

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 0):

An old CSS trick might help. Set the values for both `padding-left` and `padding-right` to a value between 15%-45% (tweak this for different screen sizes and/or div size).